# How to get a file/directory added to existing .deb file

Tags: linux, debian

We have a nicely tested executable that is installed with a .deb file.  We decided that we need to add a couple licensing files to the existing .deb file so that they are readable after installing the .deb file.  Is there an easy way to add a couple of text files to the .deb file?

I saw [add to archive](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-add-files-to-archive-file-in-linux-also-delete-files/) but it didn't mention .deb files.  Just .tar.

I also saw [deb package](https://thedarkmaster.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/how-to-create-manipulate-a-deb-file-of-a-compiled-application/) but I wasn't sure about opening the existing package without more info.

Comment: Short : Unpack the package.deb, and save a copy of the file control. And see post #3 here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/i-want-to-replace-a-file-in-a-deb-package-how-can-i-do-that-4175423669/#3 , to rebuild with the additional files.

Comment: Someone also told me about this:  http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/, which also mentions adding to the deb file.

Comment: "rpmrebuild" is reconstructing a package = rpm, from the files already installed into the OS. RPM is a a different packaging, not usable for a Debian OS ....  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/

Comment: I should have been more explicit.  At the link, it mentions the package for the debian: "On debian, the equivalent product is dpkg-repack"